# How to extract url and then download it with xpath and scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to download images using xpath in scrapy. How do i save the URLs and how i download the images they refer to?
This is what I did so far:

```
 def parse_imgur(self, response):

        image = ImagecrawlerItem()
        image['images'] = response.xpath('//a[@href]').extract()
        return image
```

Comment: You can read about the [built-in FilesPipeline here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#downloading-and-processing-files-and-images).

Comment: thats great, but does it use the URLs provided in the parse function? and if yes, how?

Comment: You need to populate a `file_urls` field in your items, as [explained here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-files-pipeline)

Comment: Populate `image_urls` for images, `file_urls` for files.